# How can I understand my standard deviation?

Tags: standard-deviation

I have some (2749) sensor output values. They range from 0 to 1769. With google spreadsheet I put it thru some calculations to get the (mean) average and standard deviation. With this I created two columns BINS and NORMDIST to create a chart. Please look at the attached image.

Mean is 53.35. Standard deviation is 61.23

What can I extrapolate from this?

A) Is one deviation 61.23, two deviation 122,46? Two deviations gives me ~95%.

B) So since my mean is 53, 95% is a effective range from 0 to 122 (as I don't have negative data)?

My chart shows while the range is from 0 to 1769, its mean is 53.

C) Is my data bad? The form of the curve the data makes is very "typical" distribution, but a little skewed to the left?

[image]

Comment: It's (very) **right** skewed. Left or right: which term to use depends on which tail is longer on a conventional histogram (or similar graph with magnitude axis horizontal). The right tail is longer. (Even a few texts get this wrong, and it's a tell-tale sign of incompetent authors.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome.

For A) No, the rule about 95% within 2 standard deviations is for normal distributions. You haven't got a normally distributed variable. For one thing, your variable has a lower bound. It also seems to have a lot of skew.

B) No, for the same reason as A.

C) Is it "bad"? Well, maybe it is and maybe it isn't, but there's nothing in what you've posted that says "this data is bad": it simply isn't normally distributed. Many variables are not.

Comment: Thanks Peter. So since my data (from the chart) isnt normally distributed then I cant use standard deviation to say if I got an result that it is confined within the x% normal standard deviation? I just started working with my data and want to learn about the takeaway

Comment: You can always count how many of your values fall within mean $\pm$ so many SD. Just don't expect results for the normal distribution to hold for your data.

Comment: That's correct.  It's possible to construct distributions where very strange things happen.

Comment: @NickCox 1710 of 1769 (~97%) has a value between 0 and mean (53). So since my data isnt normally distributed, this is the closest I get by counting check when I hit a level of certainty that I'm comfortable with

Comment: I can't easily comment on what you're comfortable with. There many possibilities for analysing these data. Why do you think it's important whether they are normally distributed, as they clearly aren't?

Comment: Also, when you have huge skew (as here) you have to be careful. Just because 97% are in a specific range, there are some big outliers which could be very important.

Comment: @NickCox I was wrong, I have 2749 elements, 1710 of them is <= mean which in turn results in 62% Now, thats bad I guess. But very close to one deviation. It follows the 64-95-99

Comment: OK, but the key question to me remains: Why compare with a normal distribution at all? This dog is not a cat; sure, but why that remark?

Comment: @NickCox Because I don't know what I'm doing here :-). I could probably chop the data to get rid of the large tail, but as you point out... this dog is not a cat. Besides simple counting, are the any other methods I can use for this data to express precision, as its not good data for standard deviation?

Comment: It's perfectly good data for SD. SD is a good thing to use for many distributions that are, or may be, very skewed, e.g. lognormal, exponential, Poisson.

Comment: What are you trying to do? (In layman's language).

Comment: @PeterFlom I want to be able to tell if my sensor value is within %, preferably about 90-95% within previous collection of data and therefor sound data. So when I get 1700 i could say that's probably due to an error as its in the upper <=1% and therefor can throw it away from further processing. Also want to learn how I can analyze my data.